# Will re-creating or designing a typeface after a custom typeface for a company infringe on its trade dress?

Tags: united-states, trademark

The video games Artifact, Dota Underlords and Dota 2 (all made by Valve) use a custom typeface on its UI, not sold comercially (it is called Radiance). If I recreate this typeface by creating a lookalike version of it, and publicily distribute it, is this a trade dress infringement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No, but it does infringe copyright

Fonts are an artistic work protected by copyright.

Comment: Not in the US. “ Eltra Corp. v. Ringer, 579 F.2d 294 (4th Cir. 1978), was a case in the United States Court of Appeals for the Fourth Circuit that determined that **typefaces** were not eligible for protection under U.S. copyright law. The US Copyright Office had refused to register a typeface design owned by Eltra Corporation, who filed suit in the U.S. District Court for the Eastern District. The district court held that the design submitted did not.”  If font means a program that draws typefaces it is copyrightable. If font means the visual typeface it is not subject to copyright.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite only so far as it is letters. A font that consists of symbols might have copyright in each of the symbols.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the location. Typefaces are not subject to copyright in the US.

[Eltra Corp. v. Ringer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eltra_Corp._v._Ringer), 579 F.2d 294 (4th Cir. 1978), was a case in the United States Court of Appeals for the Fourth Circuit that determined that typefaces were not eligible for protection under U.S. copyright law. The United States Copyright Office had refused to register a typeface design owned by Eltra Corporation, who filed suit in the U.S. District Court for the Eastern District of Virginia. The district court held that the design submitted did not qualify as a "work of art" under Regulation 202.10(c) of the 1909 Copyright Act. The appellate court affirmed this decision.

Also popular typefaces have names and the names are usually trademarked.